# syntax error using convert function

Tags: sql, converters, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to convert a timestamp into yyyymm format, and have found that this should do the trick:

```
select convert(nvarchar(6),getnow(),112);
```

I try to run this just as a POC that it will return in the proper format, but I get the following error:

```
ERROR: 42601: syntax error at or near ","
```

It works fine when I take out the style argument, but obviously does not return the desired format. I have no idea what could be happening and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Redshift - is that what you mean?

Comment: That is, Aginity Workbench for Redshift

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if Redshift allow to format like SQL Server does. 
So I suggest you to try with datepart. Something like this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(6), DATE_PART(y, getnow()) || DATE_PART(mon, getnow()) )
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, it's getdate()...

```
select convert(nvarchar(6),getdate(),112)
```

Comment: It's not sql server. He said without ",112" works fine

Comment: Bit long winded in redshift?

Answer (score 0):

This is the equivalent in Redshift:

```
select to_char(sysdate,'YYYYMM')
```